# How to reset watchOS deployment target in WatchKit extension target (XCode7 beta 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, xcode7

I develop iOS app using watchOS.

After upgrading XCode to version7 beta 6, watchOS Deployment Target(Build settings) changed to 2.0 in WatchKit extension target automatically.

Though I tried to return to 1.0, couldn't change it.

Any workaround? (without creating or duplicating watchkit extension target)

[image: I cannot select others without watchOS 2.0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Xcode 7 Beta 6 Release Notes:

> You are not be able to debug a watchOS 1 app extension in a project that also has watchOS 2 app built in the same iOS app.
>   **Workaround:** The system prefers the watchOS 2 app when both are present, so you need to remove it from the iOS app bundle. Edit the Build Phases of the iOS App to remove the watchOS 2 app as a build dependency of the iOS App and remove it from the Embed Watch Content build phase. Clean the build products, and then Run to debug the watchOS 1 app extension. (21173814)

http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_7_beta_6/Xcode_7_beta_6_Release_Notes.pdf

Comment: upvoted. Thought I understood how to set though, am wondering why watchOS1 settings are changed to watchOS2 indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same problem in simulator with Xcode 7.3.1 and could solve it by going to watch App , then go to Watch OS deployment target , there you can chose lower version based on your watch .Hope if this helps.